# Request from Traefik pod to Application Service/pod

Tags: request, traefik, portforwarding, infrastructure-as-code

what is the exact command when doing a request from Traefik pod to Application Service or pod (by any available tool that can be used like websocat)?
Or what is the exact header will use to?

Already tried different documentation but still no use.